# Asus & UBUNTU | Touchpad doesn't work at all

Tags: 14.04, kernel, asus, elantech

I have a brand new ASUS GL552VW, trying to install UBUNTU 14.04 on it.
After installation the touchpad doesn't work at all, neither shows up on xinput -list. (External mouse works.)

The kernel was 3.19 where the touchpad didn't work. after upgrading it to kernel 4.2 it worked (the touchpad).

My problem is that my own softwares are not compatible with >=4.0 kernel and I cannot upgrade them to 4.x kernel.

Any way to get the drivers of the touchpad from kernel 4.x and downgrade it to 3.x ?

Touchpad is elantech.

Computer specs: https://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks/ROG-GL552VW/

Thanks in advanced,

J.